# DML operation should not be allowed while reading SQL query from .txt file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, text, dml

My SQL query is stored in a `.txt` file, and with the help of C#, I'm reading that query and fetching data from the database.

I want to make sure no DML operation should be performed. How to achieve this?

Comment: I would argue that DML should not be your single concern in general case.

Comment: i think generally Select goes under DML so not sure how "fetching data" and "DML not allowed" goes together

Comment: forget about DML etc, just explain what you're trying to prevent

Comment: DML incorporates insert, update, delete and select; not sure what you are asking; are you confusing being able to read, write and update?

Answer (score 2):

The safest and easiest way to do it is to connect your C# application to SQL Server with a user that doesn't have permissions to run DML statements.

If your application should only be able to read data, you can give your sql user a `db_datareader` database role. If it should also be able to add, update or delete data (which is, in fact, DML - writing my answer I was thinking of DDL for some reason), combine it with `db_datawriter`.

For more information, read [Get started with Database Engine permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/getting-started-with-database-engine-permissions?view=sql-server-ver16)